# Sort total scores from highest to lowest

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table called 'Broadsheet'. This is where all the subject total scores of students in a class are aggregated.

| sn | name | math | english | french | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mary | 70 | 65 | 85 | 220 |
| 2 | michael | 90 | 70 | 95 | 255 |
| 3 | sam | 80 | 50 | 95 | 225 |

The total for each subject was gotten with this query

```
 public function getTotalMarksForStudnets($subject_id,$student_id,$table,$totField){
        $this->db->select($totField);
        $this->db->where('subject_id', $subject_id);  
        $this->db->where('student_id', $student_id); 
        $q = $this->db->get($table);
        if($q->num_rows() > 0){
            return  $q->row()->$totField;
        }else{
            return '0'; 
        }
      }
```

And displayed with this

```
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;">
            <?php 
              $totalMarks = $this->student_model->getTotalMarksForStudnets($tmrow['subject_id'],$stdName['pstudent_id'],$table,$totField);
             $gtotal =  $gtotal + $totalMarks;
             if($totalMarks!=0){
              $totSubjects =  $totSubjects + 1;
             }
            echo $totalMarks;
            ?></td>
```

While the overall total was displayed with this

```
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $gtotal;?></td>
```

Everything was going fine until I had to sort the table from the highest total score to the lowest.
The table should now look like this:

| sn | name | math | english | french | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | michael | 90 | 70 | 95 | 255 |
| 2 | sam | 80 | 50 | 95 | 225 |
| 3 | mary | 70 | 65 | 85 | 220 |

Here, I get really stuck. How do I go from here?

okay, as suggested by @titi, I did a group_by query and came up with this:

```
 public function getOverallMarksForStudnets($subject_id,$student_id,$table,$totField){
        $this->db->select_sum($totField);
        $this->db->where('subject_id', $subject_id);  
        $this->db->where('student_id', $student_id); 
        $this->db->group_by('subject_id', $subject_id);  
        $this->db->group_by('student_id', $student_id);
        $this->db->order_by($totField, 'DESC');
        $q = $this->db->get($table);
        if($q->num_rows() > 0){
            return  $q->row()->$totField;
        }else{
            return '0'; 
        }
      }
```

If this is correct, how do I display it?

After using this query,

```
 public function getTotalMarksForStudnets($subject_id,$student_id,$table,$totField){
       $this->db->select_sum($totField);
       $this->db->group_by( 'student_id', 'subject_id' );
       $this->db->order_by( $totField , 'DESC');
       $q = $this->db->get($table);
        if($q->num_rows() > 0){
            return  $q->row()->$totField;
        }else{
            return '0'; 
        }
      }
```

I get this:

| sn | name | math | english | french | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mary | 255 | 255 | 255 | 255 |
| 2 | michael | 255 | 255 | 255 | 255 |
| 3 | sam | 255 | 255 | 255 | 255 |

My database schema is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `scores_primary` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `section_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ca1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ca2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ca3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ca4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ca5` float(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ca6` float(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `affective` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `psychomotor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exam` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tot_score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `modified_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

tot_score ($totField) is what is collected in this broadsheet table under the various subjects.
$totalmarks is sum total of all tot_score ($totField). This is what I want to use to sort the scores.

Comment: So sn has no meaning?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean but sn is basically to number the columns

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `order by` statement in your query

`$this->db->order_by( $totField , 'DESC');`

`DESC` for descending
or `ASC` for ascending

**Edited**

What about something like this :

```
$this->db->select( SUM($totField) );
$this->db->group_by( 'student_id', 'subject_id' );
$this->db->order_by( $totField , 'DESC');
$q = $this->db->get($table);
```

The result will be an array with total score for each pair of student / subject, and ordered by total score.

Comment: I understand, but that would try to sort the total score for each subject. Not the overall total score.

Comment: Oh ok the query only returns score for one student and one subject ! Why don't you return eveything in one query that directly sum all scores with a `group by subject_id, student_id` ?

Comment: I have modified the post. Please help me check the query

Comment: @Mary4bills I edited my answer. The idea is to get every pair of student / subject in one query, instead of getting them one by one from multiple queries

Comment: I think we are close. Your query is getting the highest score, but now, the highest score appears in all the columns, including the subjects column.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Can you please update the original post to show that ?

Comment: What is the schema of your database table please ?

Comment: Is that something like that ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa6731 If it isn't, please modify it in the link

Comment: Here is the result array that you want : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95e09e/5
But i'm not sure to understand your db schema. If it's ok we can adapt this query to codeigniter code.